# In Dart, How to get a specific directory from script path

Tags: file, io, path, dart

I have a directory structure like:

`-project
  -dart
    -src
    -test
      -mytest.dart
  -test_data
    -testdata.csv`

And in the mytest.dart I want to access testdata.csv, what is the best way to get the absolute and platform independent path to testdata.csv from mytest.dart?

This works, but maybe there is a better way?:

```
Directory projectRoot = new Directory.fromUri(Platform.script).parent.parent.parent;
String testDataPath = path.absolute(projectRoot.path, 'test_data', 'testdata.csv');
```

Comment: Why do you need an absolute path?

Comment: Are you using the new test or the old unittest package? Your directory layout doesn't conform to the pub package layout convention, this is likely to cause troubles. https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, I know but the directory structure is not under my control. There are other languages in the root directory (implementing same library) and they all use the same test files.